# How can I get the string value of a XML element named "name" with BeatifulSoup4?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

When I try to parse a XML element (tag) "Name" with `BeatifulSoup4`

```py
exemplary_xml = '''
<SomeTag>
    <UsualTag>abc</UsualTag>
    <Name>xyz</Name>
</SomeTag>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(exemplary_xml, parser="xml")
print(soup.sometag.usualtag.string)
print(soup.sometag.name.string)
```

I'm getting an error cause it conflicts with the API [`.name` for accessing the tags name](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=name#name):

```
abc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [16], in <module>
      8 soup = BeautifulSoup(exemplary_xml, parser="lxml")
      9 print(soup.sometag.usualtag.string)
---> 10 print(soup.sometag.name.string)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'string'
```

How can I get the string value of a XML element/tag named "name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're using the `xml` via `bs4` is odd and deprecated. Use `features` and then either `find()` or `find_all()`.

For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

exemplary_xml = '''
<SomeTag>
    <UsualTag>abc</UsualTag>
    <Name>xyz</Name>
</SomeTag>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(exemplary_xml, features="xml")
print(soup.find("UsualTag").string)
print(soup.find("Name").string)
```

Output:

```
abc
xyz
```

Comment: Isn't referencing elements directly (without `find()`) more performant?

Comment: What do you mean by *more performant*?